# Can you get a computed style (css mixin) as an JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is it possible to output a computed style value as a JSON object?

```
     ...
        ready: function() {
            // themeClass = css mixin --theme-typography 
            style = this.getComputedStyleValue( this.themeClass );

            console.log( style );
            // outputs:
            // font-size: 3.0000em; 
            //   line-height: 1.0000em; 
            //   margin-top: 0.5000em;
            //   margin-bottom: 0.0000em;
            //   font-weight: 400;
            //   font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

        }
```

But it should ideally be something like:

```
         {"font-size":"3.0000em;","line-height":"1.0000em;" etc.}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const style = this.getComputedStyleValue( this.themeClass );

console.log( JSON.stringify(style) );
```

This is not really a Polymer question.

Comment: True, removed Polymer tag, and added javascript tag. However, JSON.stringify doesn't create object from the string.

Comment: @Remi I added the tags back, sorry I confused with the native javascript function `window.getComputedStyle(...)`. Are you using polymer1.0 ? I am not familiar with this, In polymer2.0 `getComputedStyleValue` doesn't exist. If it is a personal project, I would suggest you to make the move to polymer2.0, you are probably trying to do something that has no reason to be done in newer version. Polymer is currently working on the 3.0 release. Sorry I couldn't help

Comment: Thanks for the effort. For the record, 'getComputeStyleValu'e is also known in Polymer 2.0. however then in combination with ShadyCSS. See https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade